# Archiving successful but ends with BCSymbolMaps error and proceeding impossible because a similar file already exists

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild, xcode-archive

This error comes up after archiving

"A file with the name “0D43A9F9-2A23-386C-9568-E0D28099B3D5.bcsymbolmap” already exists.
To save the file, either provide a different name, or move aside or delete the existing file, and try again."

It is pertinent to note that I have another app with same name, bundleID and Team on the same Mac which I have archived successfully and published over the year.

Using Xcode 14.3 in an M1 mac.

I get the Archive Succeeded message but never get to proceed to see my archived build.
This error is due to the pods framework installation in my project. These lines of code in my framework.sh file can help shed more light on the issue.

```
if [ -d "${source}/${BCSYMBOLMAP_DIR}" ]; then
    # Locate and install any .bcsymbolmaps if present, and remove them from the .framework before the framework is copied
    find "${source}/${BCSYMBOLMAP_DIR}" -name "*.bcsymbolmap"|while read f; do
      echo "Installing $f"
      install_bcsymbolmap "$f" "$destination"
      rm "$f"
    done
    rmdir "${source}/${BCSYMBOLMAP_DIR}"
  fi
```

I have tried cleaning my build folder, deleting my existing archived files, cleared memory space, googled solutions, deleted derived data, tried all possible word combination search on Stack Overflow even tried AI suggestions. I have also tried the error suggestion of deleting the file, it regenerated on archiving again and throws the same error.

I expected to find solution and archive successfully but I never found a similar error been reported and solved.

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It might be an Xcode version issue. Xcode 14 by default no longer supports bcsymbolmaps. Try setting your Xcode to backward compatible with Xcode 13 or Xcode 13.4.1 then redo Pod Install and try if that works.

Or check if that pod has new version that fixes this issue

Comment: I use Xcode 14.3 not 14.0. Unless the issue is for all versions of 14.X. I have done pod install too, issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

remove it and redownload the framwork use pods

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What need to be removed this answer is not clear

Answer (score 0):

In My Case this issue happened since I was using a pod file and a package for a same framework so I removed the pod set up (Removed the pod name from pod file and did pod install). After this I did archive and this worked

Comment: This means in your case AJ, you use both Cocoapods and SPM right? Mine was plain Cocoapods project, no SPM. I am glad this fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This file is in FBSDK Framework, you can fix it by updating to iOS 12, and upgrade FBSDK to latest version, it works.